# Hazelcast OperationTimeoutException

Tags: hazelcast

I need help properly diagnosing com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException.

> com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: 
>   No response for 120000 ms. Aborting invocation! 
>   Invocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=GetOperation{TRADES}, partitionId=87, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invoke
>   Count=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[10.32.21.170]:17326, backupsExpected=0, backupsCompleted=0}

No response has been received!  backups-expected:0 backups-completed: 0

It appears the 120,000ms is configurable, but I don't think increasing this is the answer. 
When this does happen, all calls fail for the same reason regardless a get or set operation etc.

Can anyone provide a recommendation for what parameters should be adjusted to alleviate the issue? Perhaps it is actually a thread contention issue and increasing event threads or the likes may help. The hazelcast instance has no custom parameters at this time. Thread counts are all default.  The server is not in excessive garbage collection during the time either.

Comment: P.S. I cannot easily reproduce this issue, otherwise I would include a thread dump.  Sorry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable cause of this exception a network problem among cluster members. An unresponsive node (because of memory or GC problems etc) can also cause such issue. First thing is can be to ensure quality/performance of your network env. If you are using AWS, you can prefer instance with better network performance.

If you want to get rid of problematic nodes quickly; you can set a lower value for following system property:
"hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds" : Maximum timeout for heartbeat in seconds for a node to assume it is dead. Default is 500 seconds.

Comment: In my case, the nodes are not dead and I'm doubting a network disconnect as they are on the same physical hardware in a local VM environment. I will look into that just to be sure.  In the event that I would rather these calls just retry, is it possible to increase the attempts that hazelcast will attempt by increasing time and some attempt count parameter? For example: tryCount=250 does this mean it did attempt 250 times, or would if 120000ms was not hit first? Or invoke Count=1, does this mean only 1 attempt actually happened.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes, there is a hardcoded limit on retry count, 250. Afaik, there is no API to change this. But if it is allowed to set this to infinite; then any problematic node will cause cluster to hang infinitely.

Comment: Thanks. I will see what can be done to improve cluster performance.